# Which church fathers taught involuntary universal salvation?

Tags: soteriology, early-church, church-fathers, universalism

Which early church fathers (including those now considered heretics like Origen) pre 1054 taught that "all will be saved", including all of the dead without "hearing and believing"?  In other words, who taught a form of involuntary universal salvation?

Comment: I don't know of anyone at any time in  history teaching "involuntary" universal salvation. Many have taught that every person will eventually choose salvation. There are a lot of questions about free will if you want to examine that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the writings of the early church fathers.  How did they define "salvation?"  Saved from what?  death? sin? or both?

Comment: Origen taught salvation involved cooperation with man’s free will btw